# VLC Unity doesn't play video on Oculus Quest 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, libvlcsharp, oculusquest, vlc-unity

I am trying to use vlc unity plugin on Unity 2021.3.32f1 Personal (LTS) to show videos in Oculus Quest 2. When, I play the VLC Canvas Example scene under Demos folder, I can see a video has been displayed and playing on the canvas in the editor. But when I build the project for Oculus Quest 2 and run inside the device, only thing I can see is color orange. I can see that my scripting backend is mono, my api compatibility level is .NET Standard 2.1 and I am targeting ARMv7 architecture from "Project Settings / Player / Other Settings / Configuration". Could you  help me on finding what might have gone wrong and on where did I do wrong please?

## What I Have Expected

I have expected that I could see a video playing is displayed on Oculus Quest 2 upon build and run, just like I did on Unity Editor.

## What Happened

I couldn't see any video being played.

## Things I have tried

**1. Changing Scripting Backend to IL2CPP**

The issue persisted.

**2. Changing Targeted Architecture to ARM64**

The issue persisted.

**3. Testing Other Scenes**

After testing with Mono / ARMv7 these were the results:

- **VLC 3D Example:** On the TV screen it only displays the VLC logo and the texture doesn't update.
- **VLCMinimalPlayback:** The screen stays white and buttons are missing.
- **VLCSubtiltes:** Same as above.
- **VLCThreeSixty:** Even though I could see the text reads "the 360 video" on the headset, the screen stayed white.
- **VLCYoutubePlayback:** Same as VLCMinimalPlayback and VLCSubtiltes.

## Unity Configuration

- **Unity Version:** Unity 2021.3.32f1 Personal (LTS)
- **Project Template:** 3D (non urp)
- **Packages Installed:** Oculus XR Plugin, TextMeshPro, XR Plugin Management
- **Graphics API:** OpenGLES3

Comment: report a bug on gitlab

Comment: @mfkl , Even though I have a gitlab account, It seems like I can't log into gitlab repository of vlc with mine. Whenever I try to log into with e-mail address and password of my account, I always get "Invalid login or password" error.

Comment: this is our own gitlab, not gitlab.com. You need a new account